# Unable to load the collection in DataProvider by matching values in array

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2, magento-2.2.5, php-7

I am trying to fetch Collection of specific ids by using filters in my custom DataProvider

```
    public function getData()
{
    $id =$this->request->getParam('id');//returns 5
    $answerids=$this->helper->getRelatedAnswerArray($id);//returns array with value 9 and 10 from HelperData

    $this->collection->addFieldToFilter('answer_id',$answerids);

    $arrItems = [
        'items' => [],
    ];

    foreach ($this->getCollection() as $item) {
        $arrItems['items'][] = $item->toArray([]);
    }

    return $arrItems;
}
}
```

the `getRelatedAnswerArray()` returns 9,10 in an array but the `getData()` returns no collection at all.
But if I put the value `9,10` in an array and pass it to collection it returns the related Data.

```
$answerids=array(9,10);
```

this returns the collection but the helper data which is returning the exact same array in `$answerids` doesn't return any collection ...

My Helper Data Function is

```
    public function getRelatedAnswerArray($id)
{
    if(isset($id))
    {
        $answerRelated = $this->_answerFactory->create()->getCollection();
        $answerRelated->getSelect()
            ->joinInner(
                ['related_answer'  =>  'questionanswer'],
                'main_table.answer_id = related_answer.answer_id'
            );
        $answerRelated->addFieldToFilter('related_answer.question_id', ['eq' => $id]);
        $answerRelated->getSelect()
            ->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
            ->columns(['related_answer.answer_id']);
        foreach ($answerRelated as $key => $value)
            $postArr[]=$value->getAnswerId();
        if(!empty($postArr))
            return $postArr;
        else
            return '';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try below code with `in` if helper return Ids in array format.

```
public function getData()
{
    $id =$this->request->getParam('id');//returns 5
    $answerids=$this->helper->getRelatedAnswerArray($id);//returns array with value 9 and 10 from HelperData

    $this->collection->addFieldToFilter('answer_id',['in'=>$answerids]);

    $arrItems = [
        'items' => [],
    ];

    foreach ($this->getCollection() as $item) {
        $arrItems['items'][] = $item->toArray([]);
    }

    return $arrItems;
}
}
```

Comment: It doesnot work

Comment: I've updated my question my Helperdata Function is attached please give it a look